# Trouble using count function

Tags: c++, function

Below if my code that is supposed to ask for user for 2 numbers and output the sum of all even numbers between them. I am only having trouble using the count function as I don't believe I am setting it right and google has only helped me so far

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num1, num2, sum;
    while(num1 > num2) {
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers seperated by a space. " << endl;
        cout << "First number must be smaller then second number. " << endl;
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if(num1 % 2 == 0)
        count(== num1);
    else
        count(== num1 + 1);
    while(count(<= num2)) {
        sum = sum + count;
        count = count + 2;
    }

    cout << "The sum of the even intergers between " << num1 << "and " << num2
         << " = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing `num1` and `num2` before initializing them. Also, there's no need for a loop at all. Try some examples by hand, and you'll see that there is a formula you can use to calculate the answer directly.

Comment: "_I am only having trouble using the count function as I don't believe I am setting it right and google has only helped me so far_" - You don't have a count function and even if you did, how could google help you interpret your own code? And as @cigien pointed out: You have undefined behavior right here: `while (num1 > num2)`

Comment: I have to use a loop its whats required for this assignment

Comment: @JerryMalson That's not the point. You mention that you have a problem with a count function - but you don't have a count function. Pinpoint where your own program does the wrong thing by printing out the values it uses when it runs and you will see where it does the wrong thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I understood that part I was replying to the previous commenter before you, I actually figured out the issue with my program and it runs fine now. This is my first time learning any language so its all very new to me still. Thank you for the help anyways though

Comment: @JerryMalson I'd like to help but I'm not sure I did. :) Sorry if I confused things by commenting on the wrong thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo “*You mention that you have a problem with a count function - but you don’t have a count function*” - I’m guessing the OP is trying to use [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), but is using it incorrectly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, yes, that's probably it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no count() function in your code, nor is there a standard count() function in the standard C++ library that does what you want (though [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) comes close). Nor do you really need such a function anyway, a simple loop will suffice.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1, num2, sum = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Enter 2 numbers seperated by a space. " << endl;
        cout << "First number must be smaller then second number. " << endl;
        if (cin >> num1 >> num2) {
            if (num1 < num2) break;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ‘\n’);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    for (int num = num1; num <= num2; ++num) {
        if ((num % 2) == 0)
            sum += num;
    }

    cout << "The sum of the even integers between " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to omit `num1` and `num2` from the sum, simply change the loop accordingly:

```cpp
for (int num = num1 + 1; num < num2; ++num) {
```